# How I can get full query from relation

Tags: laravel

I have model Company with relation

```php
public function contact()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Contact::class, 'company_contacts', 'company_id', 'contact_id')
        ->wherePivot('primary', '=', true)->withPivot('primary');
}
```

I need to sort items with contact.last_name column.

So I build query

```php
$scope = $scope->leftJoin('company_contacts', "companies.id", '=', "company_contacts.company_id")
               ->leftJoin('contacts', "company_contacts.contact_id", '=', "contacts.id")
               ->groupBy(['companies.id', 'contacts.id'])
               ->select(['companies.*', 'contacts.last_name'])
               ->order('contacts.last_name');
```

But this should be more universal

Value of names and tables I can get from $relation

```php
  $relation = $scope->getRelation('contact');
  $key = $relation->getQualifiedOwnerKeyName(); // etc
```

And then substitute values into the scope-builder. But I can not get this part::

```php
 ->wherePivot('primary', '=', true)->withPivot('primary')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found public property pivotWheres of BelongsToMany class and I can use that.

```
$relation->pivotWheres
```

Comment: omg, this property is not public, so I wrote publick method in model :(